# How to show namespace in UML?

Tags: uml

How to show that certain types are in a specific namespace? Accordingly to UML 2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create the package and include those items in the package. Note that UML2 has the notion of package, that is also a namespace (and gets translated as such into programming languages).

Answer (score 2):

In UML we use package with <> stereotype for modeling namespace. See UML v.2.5. 7.4 Namespaces for details.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the package construct is close enough to the idea of namespace.  Use that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no specific "namespace" notation in UML.

Just use a package around any components that belong in a specific namespace (and use the namespace as the package name).