# UML diagram for namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, uml

Someone please tell me how to draw a **UML** diagram for namespace.
My code has class uses functionality from a `namespace` and also `namespace` that uses functions from other `namespace`.
I cannot find a proper way to draw its **UML** diagram. 
Please guide a bit.
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Namespaces cannot inherit from each other and classes cannot inherit from namespaces. What are you talking about?

Comment: @pmr sorry ... it uses its functions

Comment: Namespaces often are simply ommited in UML diagrams and the full names of entities are used instead.

Comment: maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114192/how-to-show-namespace-in-uml

Comment: Pretty sure there are boxes in UML that represent packages/modules. Just use that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a UML `package` and include those functions in that package.

Comment: But in Enterprise Architect I could not find package with UML option.

Comment: @PabitraDash I always simply use Microsoft Visio Pro so don't have to worry about some  UML Diagram not being supported.